# PHP: Relative path doesn't work

Tags: php, path, relative-path, include-path

I want to include a file called `script.php` this file is in the `includes` folder.
When I do this:
`include('/includes/script.php');`

There is nothing happend, I get a error message that the file is not found. But when I do this:
`include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/script.php');`

It works!, But `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns the base path of the document right? 
But why is `/includes/script.php` not working? When you start a path with `/` means you go to the document root right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you start with / you are @ the Document root, but normaly your code on the server is in some subfolders you can use './includes/script.php'. The point means in the actual directory the includes folder.